# Change the color of a QRubberBand

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to change the color of a QRubberBand. I tried this:

```
QRubberBand* rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this->graphicsView);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Foreground, QBrush(Qt::green));
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, QBrush(Qt::red));

rubberBand->setPalette(palette);

rubberBand->resize(30, 30);
rubberBand->show();
```

but the rubberband that appears is the standard black dotted one. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual rendering depends on the platform, but for Windows (perhaps others), you set the `QPalette::Highlight` color role. This example works:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QRubberBand band(QRubberBand::Rectangle);

  QPalette pal;
  pal.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(Qt::red));
  band.setPalette(pal);

  band.resize(30, 30);
  band.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

If you are on a different platform, let me know and I can see what works for that platform.

**However**, since you refer to a graphics view, I'm wondering if you mean the black dotted line that appears around selected items? That is something completely different, and doesn't involve the `QRubberBand` at all. If that is the case, you might need to update the question.

BTW, I looked at the code for `QWindowsVistaStyle` to track down the answer. If you are on a different platform and have access to the source, you can look in the correct style class for that platform.

**UPDATE** Looks like you are out of luck with Ubuntu. That uses `QCleanLooksStyle`, which calls `QWindowsStyle` for a rubber band. In there, the colors are hard-coded:

```
QPixmap tiledPixmap(16, 16);
QPainter pixmapPainter(&tiledPixmap);
pixmapPainter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
pixmapPainter.setBrush(Qt::Dense4Pattern);
pixmapPainter.setBackground(Qt::white);
pixmapPainter.setBackgroundMode(Qt::OpaqueMode);
pixmapPainter.drawRect(0, 0, tiledPixmap.width(), tiledPixmap.height());
... etc ...
```

Also, the [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-reference.html) doesn't list `QRubberBand` as obeying any styles. If you really need a different color, your only option might be to subclass `QRubberBand` and implement `paintEvent`. Bummer.

Comment: Interesting - first I was shocked when I saw the rubberband appear in the corner of my screen without being inside of a QMainWindow - that is neat. Second, you got it right, I was talking about the normal rubberband, not the highlighting that occurs around a selected item. Last, the dotted rubberband was indeed still gray/black for me (Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. It is sad to see that some parts of Qt are not behaviorally the same across platforms :(

Comment: Is there not a way to override QCleanLooksStyle? What about a custom QRubberBand::paintEvent()?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is using QGraphicsColorEffect, as follows:

```
QGraphicsColorizeEffect *e = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(rubberBand_);
e->setColor(QColor("red"));
rubberBand_->setGraphicsEffect(e);
```

However, QGraphicsEffects are deprecated in Qt 4.8 with the reason "flawed design". Color and dropshadow effects are used extensively in my projects to render non-widget items, menus and fonts. I hope Nokia would provide equivalent solutions before deprecate the entire feature.